# Django - not receiving AJAX data sent

Tags: django, ajax

I make an AJAX call, which should send data to the backend. In the backend, I `print` the data that has been sent from the frontend, however `None` is returned. This is unexpected, as the network tab(in chrome) confirms the AJAX request was successfully made, with the correct data appended to it. This make me think something is wrong with the **backend**(Django).

**HTML(signup.html):**

```
<form id="signup_form">
      {% for field in form %}
          {{ field }}
          <br>
      {% endfor %}
      <button class="signup-btn btn btn-primary">Sign up</button>
</form>

<div id="testbox"></div>
```

**Javascript/AJAX CODE**:

```
    var delayTimer;

    $('#signup_form').keyup(function() {
        clearTimeout(delayTimer);
        delayTimer = setTimeout(function () {
            var usernameVal = $("#username_signup").val();
            // This returns expected result(value in input box)
            console.log(usernameVal);

            $.ajax({
                url: '/users/ajax/signup',
                data: {
                    'usernameVal': usernameVal,
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#testbox').text(data['usernameVal']);
                }
            });
        }, 1000);
    });
```

**views.py**:

```
// Renders form and signup page
def signup(request):
    context ={}
    form = SignupForm()

    context['form'] = form
    return render(request, 'signup.html', context)

// Handles AJAX (This is the view AJAX calls (url = /users/ajax/signup))
def ajax_signup(request):
    form = SignupForm(request.GET)

    if form.is_valid():
        // This line below is printed successfully
        print("WORKS")
        // This line below returns None unexpectedly
        print(form.cleaned_data.get("usernameVal"))
        return JsonResponse({'usernameVal': form.cleaned_data.get("usernameVal")})
    else:
        print(form.errors)
        return JsonResponse({'hello': 'not working'})
```

**Signup Form**:

```
class SignupForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(min_length=4, max_length=150, required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Username (min 4 characters)', 'id': 'username_signup'}))
    email = forms.EmailField(min_length=3, required=False, widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email', 'id': 'email_signup'}))
    password = forms.CharField(min_length=8, required=False, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password (min 8 characters)', 'id': 'password_signup'}))
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Confirm Password', 'id': 'confirmpass_signup'}))
```

Comment: Can you share the `SignupForm`?

Comment: @IainShelvington Yes sure, please check my original post.

Comment: @IainShelvington I have updated the original post; please take a look there. Thank you.

Comment: The field is named `username` not `usernameVal`. The reason the form is valid is that it has no required fields

Comment: @IainShelvington Hello, I have changed `username` to `usernameVal` and everything works as expected, thank you.

Comment: @IainShelvington However I am still unsure why. Can you explain further?

Comment: @IainShelvington I don't understand why I had to change `username` to `usernameVal` in my forms, as I am referencing the `id` of this field in my code. Why did I have to do this in order for this to work? Which bits of the code need reference to this form field? Thank you.